# knockout custom binding with bootstrap datepicker showing wrong view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I want to display a datepicker to only display year and month with the current month as the default view. The problem is that it still shows the day view and I can't see what's wrong, any suggestions?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datePickerMonthYear =
    init: (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) ->
        value = valueAccessor()
        $('#dpMonths').data({date: value()});
        $('#dpMonths').datepicker('update');

        $(element).datepicker(
            viewMode: "years", 
            minViewMode: "months"
        ).on('changeDate', (ev) ->  
            $(this).datepicker('hide')
        ).on('click',  (ev) ->
            $(this).datepicker('show')
        )
        ko.bindingHandlers.validationCore.init(element, valueAccessor,allBindingsAccessor)
    ,
    update: (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) ->
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="dpMonths" class="input-append date" data-date-minviewmode="months" data-date-viewmode="years" data-date-format="mm/yyyy" data-bind="datePickerMonthYear: startDate">
    <input class="span2" type="text" readonly="" data-bind="value: startDate">
    <span class="add-on">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: which plug-in are you using? Please post a jsFiddle

Comment: Sorry, I was wondering why it wasn't working with Firefox (the calander doesn't move when prev or next is clicked), ok in chrome though. This isn't the same setup, but even still, not right... http://jsfiddle.net/DcafD/25/

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), you need to set the `startView` property:

```
$(element).datepicker({
    startView: year
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `dateFormat`  instead of `format` in [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DcafD/25/) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
        viewMode: "months", 
        minViewMode: "years",
        startView: "month"
    });
});
```

works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jham/ESX6Z/1/